# Seeking a recommendation for an elevation or altitude site

Tags: data-request, geospatial

What is a good website to find an elevation or altitude ?

Must be able to upload my kml/kmz to the site for review .

Must have Latitude, Longitude and elevation or altitude

I have personally used Google Earth Pro.

Comment: It isn't clear what elevation or altitude information you are looking for. Do you mean specifically for geographic features? If so, what level of coverage of the earth do you require? Also, what you mean that you want your kml/kmz file to be "reviewed" by the site. It might also be helpful to say what it is that Google Earth Pro does, or does not provide, that you are looking for.

Comment: usgs.gov has pretty good elevation data

Comment: It sounds like you're not looking for a dataset, but rather an interactive website.